# How to Import Local Package in Golang

Tags: go, import, package, local

i have a problem. I cannot import local packages in my application.

```
type Post struct {
    URL     string `json:"url,omitempty"`
    Caption string `json:"caption,omitempty"`
    Likes   []User `json:"likes,omitempty"` // Can not import User from package user
}
```

```
type User struct {
    Name       string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Password   string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Followers  []User `json:"followers,omitempty"`
    Followings []User `json:"followings,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: See https://go.dev/doc/code for a tutorial on how to develop a Go module.  A section in the document describes how to work withe packages in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample structure for your scenario as follows:

Assuming the Project Structure look like something this:

```
project-villa/      //Name of your Project

    model/
    -user.go    //this file will contain your User Structure
    repository/
    -post.go   //this file will hold your Post structure and the rest piece of code
    handler/
    driver/
    main.go
```

Step1:- initialize the module

```
go mod init project-villa
```

OR

```
go mod init github.com/user-name/project-villa
```

The mod will manage the module dependency itself. Anyhow if it doesn't you can import it explicitly.
It will look like this:

```
github.com/random/project-villa/models




 type Post struct {
    URL     string `json:"url,omitempty"`
    Caption string `json:"caption,omitempty"`
    Likes   []models.User `json:"likes,omitempty"` //you can use it like this
}
```

For the reference you can follow the [link](https://go.dev/doc/code) of official go dev. Here you will get the `Importing packages from your module`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I did not see any sample of importing any local packages, can you please giving more samples on this ?